# Error fetching Json File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, web-scraping

I am trying to make code for a Script to check Validity of a Coupon Code on Udemy. The course id is "1524736" and CouponCode for this case is "UDEMYSTUDIO".

I am requesting for info from the site using $.getJSON but it is not working with the Error:

> Failed to load
>   https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/1524736/me/?components=redeem_coupon&couponCode=UDEMYSTUDIO:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How can i fix it and is there any better way to do it?
Thanks in Advance.

Below is the code that i am using.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>

    <script>
        var url= 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/1524736/me/?components=redeem_coupon&couponCode=UDEMYSTUDIO'
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        var text = `Apply_State: ${data.redeem_coupon.is_applied}<br>
                    Error: ${data.redeem_coupon.error}<br>
                    Code: ${data.redeem_coupon.code}`


        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access
>   selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than
>   the site currently in use. A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP
>   request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol,
>   or port than the one from which the current document originated.

Since your siteis hosted in a different domain than udemy's, and then don't explicitly allow you to access their resources from your specific domain (or all domains), the browser will reject the response since it enforces the CORS policy.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

How do you fix this?

1. Check if udemy exposes an api that you can use or some kind of cross domain pattern ([jsonp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?).
2. Create a request to your server (same domain), the server will create a server to server request to udemy and return a response.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you please elaborate on how should it be implemented because i am a beginner in Web Development and a little more help would be really make things easier for me.